# NullPointerException when extending BaseClass where driver is initialised

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, testng

I get NullPointerException when trying to separate driver initialization to a separate class.
I'm a beginner at Java, what am I doing wrong here?

BaseTest.java

```
package common;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
public class BaseTest { 

    public static WebDriver driver = null;
    
    @BeforeSuite
    public void launchBrowser() {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
    
    @AfterSuite
    public void closeBrowser() {
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Test.java

```
package ui;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import common.BaseTest;

public class ListenerDemoTest extends BaseTest{
    @Test
    public void something() {
        driver.get("https.//google.com");
    }
}
```

Error Message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.get(String)" because "ui.ListenerDemoTest.driver" is null
    at ui.ListenerDemoTest.something(ListenerDemoTest.java:10)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    ...
```

Comment: Change `ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();` to `driver = new ChromeDriver();`. Because `driver` was already initialized with `public static WebDriver driver = null;`. I'm not familiar with `WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();`, make sure it set up the `driver` correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the problem is you initialized the driver with the null value and not updating it inside the method

Update the BaseTest

```
public class BaseTest {
    ChromeDriver driver;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void launchBrowser() {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void closeBrowser() {
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Also, there is a typo in your URL
`driver.get("https://google.com");`

Comment: `so the problem is you have two instances of Driver` - sir where are two instance in OP question ?

Comment: my bad, not instance but initialized with the null value and not updating it inside the method

Answer (score 4):

In `BaseTest`, you have initialized the `WebDriver driver` instance to null but you never updated the reference with the actual value as part of the `@BeforeSuite` setup. So the reference would be always null causing the NullPointerException exception. In the `@BeforeSuite` method you have done the variable shadowing where instead of updating the `driver` instance, you have created the local instance called `driver` and failed to update the static instance reference.

The required change is

```
    @BeforeSuite
    public void launchBrowser() {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
```